# how to calibrate mpu6050 sensor using python and multiwii serial protocol?

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, pyserial

I have multiwii board connected to raspberry pi 3A and I want to calibrate the mpu6050 sensor from raspberry pi using python programming, can anyone help me out on how I can program this, please?

Comment: There are tons of examples for the MPU6050 on the internet. Please try it on your own and ask more specific questions. I´m sure that you will receive help with specific problems.

Comment: I'm new to this. So I'm asking

Answer (score 0):

Try to be more specific in you questions for te next times.

But, to calibrate a Gyro you should take a look at [this tutorial.](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-sensorlab-gyroscope-calibration). Or if you are a really begginer and wants to learn how to use the sensor, take a look to [this.](https://learn.adafruit.com/mpu6050-6-dof-accelerometer-and-gyro)

[This](https://learn.adafruit.com/lsm303-accelerometer-slash-compass-breakout/coding) and [this](https://learn.adafruit.com/lsm303-accelerometer-slash-compass-breakout/python-circuitpython) tutorial are also useful.